# Better way than if else if else... for linear interpolation

Tags: c++, interpolation

question is easy. 
Lets say you have function

```
double interpolate (double x);
```

and you have a table that has map of known x-> y
for example
 5    15
 7    18
 10   22
**note:** real tables are bigger ofc, this is just example.

so for 8 you would return 18+((8-7)/(10-7))*(22-18)=19.3333333

One cool way I found is 
http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/cpp-map-interp.html
(long story short it uses std::map, key= x, value = y for x->y data pairs).

If somebody asks what is the if else if else way in title 
it is basically:

```
if ((x>=5) && (x<=7))
{
//interpolate
}
else 
     if((x>=7) && x<=10)
     {
      //interpolate
     }
```

So is there a more clever way to do it or map way is the state of the art?  :)

Btw I prefer soutions in C++  but obviously any language solution that has 1:1 mapping to C++ is nice.

Comment: Does not seem to apply in this case, but anyway: if the 'x' values of interpolation points are equally spaced, you can use a modulo operation to find the index of the first value that is >= query_value, in constant time. Some linear transformations are necessary.

Comment: yeah I intentionally made not equidistant to make clear that I want linear interpolation, but that intervals arent necessarily the same.

Comment: Though, the modulo method can still work if you can make the intervals equidistant after application of some function.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl So what's the problem with the map method you refer to?? Especially if you mention you have a big number of x/y pairs `std::map` should be the way to go (`if/else if` is far to tedious). Your question seems more to be after, how you could fill your table data in an efficient way, as your responses to the first 2 answers suggest.

Comment: @g-makulik like i said: "So is there a more clever way to do it or map way is the state of the art? :)"     I just wanna know what is the best way.

Comment: You are looking for a more clever way to do it... how do you define "clever"?  Fewer lines of code?  More compact data structure?  Better performance?  Fewer cache misses?  How many pairs fo numbers do you have?  Is the table static or dynamic?  Is the table integers or might it be doubles?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation

Comment: @PureVida - doubles, lets say that tables can be known at compile time or at run time, actually idk if that affects the solution. and clever= minimum amount of code that has same complexity as the best possible solution. ofc  if it is slover by a constant factor 184x it sucks no matter that it has same complexity.

Answer (score 32):

Well, the easiest way I can think of would be using a binary search to find the point where your point lies. Try to avoid maps if you can, as they are very slow in practice.

This is a simple way:

```
const double INF = 1.e100;
vector<pair<double, double> > table;
double interpolate(double x) {
    // Assumes that "table" is sorted by .first
    // Check if x is out of bound
    if (x > table.back().first) return INF;
    if (x < table[0].first) return -INF;
    vector<pair<double, double> >::iterator it, it2;
    // INFINITY is defined in math.h in the glibc implementation
    it = lower_bound(table.begin(), table.end(), make_pair(x, -INF));
    // Corner case
    if (it == table.begin()) return it->second;
    it2 = it;
    --it2;
    return it2->second + (it->second - it2->second)*(x - it2->first)/(it->first - it2->first);
}
int main() {
    table.push_back(make_pair(5., 15.));
    table.push_back(make_pair(7., 18.));
    table.push_back(make_pair(10., 22.));
    // If you are not sure if table is sorted:
    sort(table.begin(), table.end());
    printf("%f\n", interpolate(8.));
    printf("%f\n", interpolate(10.));
    printf("%f\n", interpolate(10.1));
}
```

Comment: This looks very much like what the op wants. Do you know how exactly `lower_bounds` performs its binary search? According to the docs, it will achieve O(logN) on any random access iterator. Nice!

Comment: I don't know implementation details, but lower_bound uses the operator< to do a binary search (indeed in O(logN)).

Comment: To achieve more continuous result, the output when x is out of range should better be the boundary value, for example if(x > table.back().first) return table.back().second;

Comment: I don't agree with that. The function should indicate that the value is out of bound, and the programmer should treat this case. Maybe he wants to do what you suggested, maybe he wants to [extrapolate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation), and maybe he wants to tell the user that the value is out of bound.

Comment: @DanielFleischman please elaborate on why you said maps are slow in practice? Is it just because of cache locality, or something else?

Comment: Yes, it is because of cache locality. Maps are usually implemented with a red-black tree, which gives you not only the cache locality problem, but also a memory overhead to store all the pointers. Benchmark it yourself and be surprised :)

Comment: Almost 10 years later update: I tried this and also a map version of it. Surprisingly the map version was not slower, but a bit faster even for random interpolation of a size N=1000 tabulated function (doubles). The vector version did get faster (though not a lot) for larger N. Explained by larger cache in modern CPU's perhaps? What was more surprising though was that a "hand-written" binary search on vectors was more than two times faster than the lower_bound-based version. Go figure.

Answer (score 5):

You can use a binary search tree to store the interpolation data. This is beneficial when you have a large set of N interpolation points, as interpolation can then be performed in O(log N) time. However, in your example, this does not seem to be the case, and the linear search suggested by RedX is more appropriate.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <map>

static double interpolate (double x, const std::map<double, double> &table)
{
    assert(table.size() > 0);

    std::map<double, double>::const_iterator it = table.lower_bound(x);

    if (it == table.end()) {
        return table.rbegin()->second;
    } else {
        if (it == table.begin()) {
            return it->second;
        } else {
            double x2 = it->first;
            double y2 = it->second;
            --it;
            double x1 = it->first;
            double y1 = it->second;
            double p = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1);
            return (1 - p) * y1 + p * y2;
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::map<double, double> table;
    table.insert(std::pair<double, double>(5, 6));
    table.insert(std::pair<double, double>(8, 4));
    table.insert(std::pair<double, double>(9, 5));

    double y = interpolate(5.1, table);

    printf("%f\n", y);
}
```

Comment: note that my example is unreasonably small for demonstration purposes, real data has >5 points.

Comment: btw you re doing the thing I linked to in my Q. :) Just without boost:assign

Answer (score 4):

Store your points sorted:

```
index X    Y
1     1 -> 3
2     3 -> 7
3     10-> 8
```

Then loop from max to min and as soon as you get below a number you know it the one you want.

You want let's say `6` so:

```
// pseudo
for i = 3 to 1
  if x[i] <= 6
    // you found your range!
    // interpolate between x[i] and x[i - 1]
    break; // Do not look any further
  end
end
```

Comment: A search tree (AVL/RB) might be more efficient when the size of the table is not very small.

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak with optimizations enabled, this loop benefits from branch prediction, so one can expect reasonable speed

Comment: @stefan the efficiency is almost certainly still going to be linear.

Comment: as a side note: wouldn't it be a bit slightly more efficient to go through the array from the start?

Comment: @stefan Probably it will make (close to) no difference in small arrays and in big ones it would be best to use a map anyway because of look-up time.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I guess that you should think in a map between those intervals and the natural nummbers. I mean, just label the intervals and use a switch:

```
switch(I) {

    case Int1: //whatever
        break;

      ...

    default:

}
```

I don't know, it's the first thing that I thought of.

**EDIT** Switch is more efficient than if-else if your numbers are within a relative small interval (that's something to take into account when doing the mapping)

Comment: but isnt mapping from x to I(int used in switch) pretty much the problem Im trying to solve?

Answer (score 3):

If your x-coordinates must be irregularly spaced, then store the x-coordinates in sorted order, and use a binary search to find the nearest coordinate, for example using Daniel Fleischman's answer.

However, if your problem permits it, consider pre-interpolating to regularly spaced data.  So

```
   5 15
   7 18
   10 22
```

becomes

```
   5 15
   6 16.5
   7 18
   8 19.3333333
   9 20.6666667
   10 22
```

Then at run-time you can interpolate with O(1) using something like this:

```
double interp1( double x0, double dx, double* y, int n, double xi )
{
   double f = ( xi - x0 ) / dx;
   if (f<0) return y[0];
   if (f>=(n-1)) return y[n-1];
   int i = (int) f;
   double w = f-(double)i;
   return dy[i]*(1.0-w) + dy[i+1]*w;
}
```

using

```
double y[6] = {15,16.5,18,19.3333333, 20.6666667, 22 }
double yi = interp1( 5.0 , 1.0 , y, 5, xi );
```

This isn't necessarily suitable for every problem -- you could end up losing accuracy (if there's no nice grid that contains all your x-samples), and it could have a bad cache penalty if it would make your table much much bigger.  But it's a good option for cases where you have some control over the x-coordinates to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

How you've already got it is fairly readable and understandable, and there's a lot to be said for that over a "clever" solution. You can however do away with the lower bounds check and clumsy `&&` because the sequence is ordered:

```
if (x < 5)
  return 0;
else if (x <= 7)
  // interpolate
else if (x <= 10)
  // interpolate
...
```