# evaluating function only defined by table, C++

Tags: c++, math, interpolation

I'd like to evaluate a function in C++, but I have the values only defined in table such as the following:

```
entry #  en(eV)   Effective Qm - Defined in introduction(1E-16*cm^2)

   1        0     4.96
   2    0.001     4.98
   3    0.002     5.02
   4    0.003     5.07
   5    0.005     5.12
   6    0.007     5.15
   7   0.0085     5.18
```

I'd like to have a function, which returns Effective Qm for each energy. Ideally interpolated value, but for now I'll be happy with just rounding to the closest energy for which the Qm is known and giving that as a result. I have no idea how this should be done. I know this would be easy in Mathematica, but the rest of the code is much faster in C++.

Comment: where/how is your table stored?

Comment: I only have the text file formatted as in the question. If you tell me how should I store it for the evaluation to be easy, I'll do it

Comment: Are you asking us how to parse a text file, design a class, or what?

Comment: Please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516915/read-numeric-data-from-a-text-file-in-c

Comment: Why the close votes? Interpolation is a well-defined mathematical operation, but unlike `std::cos()` there's no obvious method in `<cmath>` to do it. There's a question on [_lineair_ interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396860/better-way-than-if-else-if-else-for-linear-interpolation) but that's more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you create a struct for your data:

```
struct energyEntry {
    double energy;
    double Qm;
};
```

I'm going to assume you can load the data into a vector. Your first-level approach that you're asking help for is just to load the data and find the closest entry. You just keep track of the closest entry and update that as you iterate through the data. At the end you'll have the closest item.

```
std::vector<energyEntry> entries;
loadEntries(entries); // assuming you can do this

double targetEnergy = 0.0015; // value you want to look up

int best = 0;
for (int x = 1; x < entries.size(); x++)
{
    if (fabs(entries[x].energy-targetEnergy) < fabs(entries[best].energy-targetEnergy))
        best = x;
}

cout << "Qm is " << entries[best].Qm << "\n";
```

Some caveats here. Make sure you pass the vector to `loadEntries` by reference. You might need to do floating point compares if precision matters. You probably want this code in a function. But, this gets you started.

If you want to do more, you can do regression to try to model the data (linear, logistic, or a neural network). Or, you can just interpolate if you fall between two points. But that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Nathan S contributed as answer which implements a manual linear search. There's already a better solution in C++. Assuming the same setup:

```
struct energyEntry {
    double energy;
    double Qm;
};
std::vector<energyEntry> entries = loadEntries(); 

double targetEnergy = 0.0015; // value you want to look up
```

This is how it's done properly in C++:

```
auto iter = upper_bound(begin(entries), end(entries), targetEnergy, 
  [](energyEntry ee, double target) { return ee.energy < target; });
if (iter != end(entries)) {
    // *iter is bigger than target
    if (iter != begin(entries)) {
         // iter-1 exists, and it was smaller or equal.
    } else {
       // Target is smaller than smallest value in table
    }
 } else {
    // Value is bigger than largest value in table
 }
```

It's up to you how you exactly handle the three cases.