# Is there a std implementation for a lookup table?

Tags: c++11, lookup-tables

I want to obtain a material property from a lookup table with linear interpolation. Is there a std implementation that does something like that?

Else I would implement by own, using two vectors x and y. Finding the right position in x with lower_bound and then interpolate with x. Could I do better?

Comment: See [Better way than if else if else... for linear interpolation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396860/better-way-than-if-else-if-else-for-linear-interpolation).  There's nothing built in, no...you'd have to look around for a library or write your own.

Answer (score 0):

You might use an ordered [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map). So for a given number `n`, get the map entry below it (with [lower_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/lower_bound)) and the map entry above it (with [upper_bound](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/upper_bound), or simply by incrementing the iterator given by `lower_bound`), then interpolate.

You could also use a simple vector or array of pairs which you would have sorted by their key, then code a dichotomical access (binary search). This is probably faster than `std::map` (e.g. because of cache locality).

Comment: Once you have the result of `lower_bound`, why do you need to call `upper_bound`? You get an iterator, and incrementing that iterator already gives you the correct result, does it not?

Comment: Thanks, improved my answer!

Comment: This is a reasonable first approximation for code which is known not performance-critical. But lookup tables are generally quite stable which makes a sorted `std::vector<std::pair<X,Y>>` the best initial choice for code which is suspected to be performance-critical.